# How can I read a certain information from a line in a text file?

Tags: c

I'm trying to read the CIN code for patients between 1997 and 2000 dates from file `patient.txt`. It mostly works well but in the specific 1981 date, which there are two of patients with this same date, it seems to display only the CIN code for the first patient , Why is that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void main()
{ 
    FILE *fichier;
    fichier = fopen("patient.txt", "w");
    if (fichier != NULL) printf("le fichie patient.txt est cree !\n");
    fprintf(fichier, "voici la liste de nos patients!\n");
    fprintf(fichier, "nom:Tahar prenom:Jaafer CIN:14610862 Date De Naissance:14/01/2002\n");
    fprintf(fichier, "nom:Ali prenom:Khalfalh CIN:26540392 Date De Naissance:15/02/1997\n");
    fprintf(fichier, "nom:Mohamed prenom:Gamadi CIN:15401256 Date De Naissance:12/12/2000\n");
    fprintf(fichier, "nom:Samir prenom:Alouani CIN:11226508 Date De Naissance:7/02/1981\n");
    fprintf(fichier, "nom:Haj prenom:Mohamed ali CIN:12012725 Date De Naissance:15/05/2005\n");
    fprintf(fichier, "nom:Farah prenom:Bouanane CIN:12751802 Date De Naissance:18/07/1981\n");
    fclose(fichier);
    char sntnc[100];
    int pos;
    char *ptr1[50], *ptr2[50];
    fichier = fopen("patient.txt", "r");
    char word[8] = "/1981\n", nm_cin[5];
    int c;
    while ((c = getc(fichier)) != EOF)
    {fgets(sntnc, 100, fichier);
        if (strstr(sntnc, word) != 0)
        {printf("found\n");
            *ptr1 = strstr(sntnc, "CIN");
            *ptr2 = strstr(sntnc, "\n");
            pos = (*ptr1 - *ptr2) + 2;
            fseek(fichier, pos, SEEK_CUR);
            fscanf(fichier, "%s", nm_cin);
            printf("CIN=%s\n", nm_cin);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the need to seek? You already have the whole line read as a string. And what is the `c=getc(fichier)` for which precedes `fgets()`? Better as `while(fgets(sntnc, sizeof sntnc, fichier) != NULL)`. You can use `sscanf()` on a string, or `strncpy()`.

Comment: `char *ptr1[50], *ptr2[50];` ==> `char *ptr1, *ptr2;` you want simple pointers, not arrays of 50 pointers. Also, turn on and **mind your compiler warnings**.

Comment: Hint: `strncpy()`, **not** `*x = y` when copying strings.

Comment: i used`fseek()` to move the cursor in the current readed line to the position of CIN word and then used `fscanf(fichier,"%s",nm_cin)` to read the whole number of cin and then print it , while i used `c=getc(fichier)!=EOF` to quit the while loop when it reachs end of file and it works but for some reason when i used a`(!feof(fichier) )` condition in while loop or when using your condition `while(fgets(sntnc,sizeof sntnc,fichier) !=NULL)` it doesnt work for 1981 configuration it just printf found one time while it's existed 2 times in the file

Comment: i am not copying strings.  `strstr()` returns ptr1 and ptr2 pointers will point to the beginning of each word `CIN` and `\n` in the readed string (line) and then substracting them and declating the result with 2 to be able to read the CIN number  up from the first digit.

Comment: @TaharJaafer Did you potentially get the tagging of your question wrong (C# instead of C)?. You can edit your post and change the tag ion order not to confuse readers.

Comment: @FrankPI Thx! now edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two major errors.

1. `nm_cin[5]` - The array is too short to store the 8-digit CIN. The `fscanf()` stores beyond the end of the array, overwrites another variable, and the program ceases to behave well-defined. Make it `nm_cin[9]`.
2. After `fseek()` and `fscanf()` the file position is in the middle of the line and the next `fgets()` continues reading from there. This causes the program to get out of step. Better don't disturb the read sequence. *You already have the whole line read as a string*, as Weather Vane noted, so you can read the CIN from the `sntnc` buffer. Change

   ```
               pos = (*ptr1 - *ptr2) + 2;
               fseek(fichier, pos, SEEK_CUR);
               fscanf(fichier, "%s", nm_cin);
   ```

   to

   ```
               sscanf(*ptr1+4, "%8s", nm_cin);
   ```

Comment: THANKS VERY MUCH Yess I knew that nm_cin[5] is false from the beginning I just keep it like that cuz the program behaved like working but what I really have missed is that when I used `fseek()` I changed the file position so the next `fgets() ` won't read the right sentence as you mentioned thank you again!!